# React native navigation with a Flatlist in a stateless component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create stateless component to display a Flatlist and I am struggling with the navigation.

This is my 'main' app.js, stripped down:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Strip from '../components/Strip'

export default class FetchData extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        ...
    }


    render(){
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            ...
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <Strip props={this.state.dataSource.strips} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')} >
        <View style={{width: 136}}>
            ...
            <Text>some text</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Strip = (props) => {
    return Object.keys(props).map(function(key, i) {
        return Object.keys(props[key]).map((strips, i) => {
            var strip = props[key][strips];
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>{strip.title}</Text>
                    <FlatList horizontal
                        data={strip.someobjects}
                        renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
                    />     
                </View>
            )
        });
    })
}

export default Strip;
```

The list is displayed but, of course, when I touch an item I get the 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')' error.

I know that I can't use this.props.navigation.navigate on a stateless component but I just don't understand how I can pass the navigation props via a flatlist in a stateless component.

It has to be something really simple like using *navigate('Details')* and put *const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;* somewhere. But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `navigate` from `Strip` component, provide an `onPress` handler to `Strip` and navigate from there. If `FetchData` is part of `StackNavigator` then you could easily `navigate` from this component.

Consider following example

```
...
export default class FetchData extends React.Component {
 ...
 handleOnPress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')
 }

 render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading){
   ...
  }
  return (
   <View>
    <Strip 
     props={this.state.dataSource.strips} 
     onPress={this.handleOnPress} 
    />
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

In the `Strip` component, you can bind the `onPress` handler

```
 const Strip = (props) => {
  renderItem = ({item}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} >
    <View style={{width: 136}}>
     ...
    <Text>some text</Text>
   </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );

 return Object.keys(props).map(function(key, i) {
  return Object.keys(props[key]).map((strips, i) => {
   var strip = props[key][strips];
    return(
     <View>
      <Text>{strip.title}</Text>
       <FlatList horizontal
         data={strip.someobjects}
         renderItem={({item}) => renderItem(item)}
       />     
      </View>
     )
  });
})
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Ah, I like this approach. Getting undefined is not an object this time (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate').

Comment: Is `FetchData` component part of `StackNavigator`?

Comment: I now realise that it's not. I'll take this chance to refactor and separate the logic from the view. Thank you Prasun Pal.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function for navigation in parent and pass it to child via props.

Eg:

Parent

---

```
parentNavigate(destination){
 this.props.navigation.navigate(destination);
}

render(){
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            ...
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <Strip props={this.state.dataSource.strips} parentNavigate={(destination) => this.parentNavigate(destination)}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Child

---

```
renderItem = (item, parentNavigate) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={parentNavigate('Details')} >
        <View style={{width: 136}}>
            ...
            <Text>some text</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Strip = (props, parentNavigate) => {
    return Object.keys(props).map(function(key, i) {
        return Object.keys(props[key]).map((strips, i) => {
            var strip = props[key][strips];
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>{strip.title}</Text>
                    <FlatList horizontal
                        data={strip.someobjects}
                        renderItem={(item, parentNavigate) => this.renderItem(item, parentNavigate)}
                    />     
                </View>
            )
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harikrishnan. I see the logic and I can try to work on this. At the moment I get 'undefined is not a function (evaluating 'parentNavigate('Details')').